# Degree of splitting field over F and irreducible polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $f(x) ∈ F[x]$ is irreducible of degree $n > 0$, and L is the splitting field of f(x) over F. I want to show that $n|[L : F]$ and also give an example to show that $n = [L : F]$ can occur.I know if $n$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of a over $F$, then $[F(a) :F]=n$..but does that help?

Comment: yes it helps since $F\subset F(a)\subset L$ and so $[L:F]=[L:F(a)]\cdot [F(a):F]$

Comment: so since [F(a):F]=n in this case so it follows [L:F] is a multiple of n? And it holds even if f(x) may not be minimal?

Comment: yes to your first question. but if f isnt minimal you dont know that [F(a):F]=n

Comment: oh you said f is irreducible. then its minimal

Comment: irreducible does not imply minimal though right? And did we use the fact L is specifically a splitting field of f(x) over F somehow?

Comment: doesnt it? and no, just that $L$ contains F(a)

Comment: I am still not sure about the irreducible implies minimal part but ok for the example of how the equality holds, can i take L=C the field of complex numbers and F = R? so that L=F(i)

Comment: Your example is ok, you just need to mention what polynomial $\mathbb{C}$ is the splitting field of. Regarding the irreducibility implies minimal question: In the start of a course on Galois theory you should prove the result that the minimal polynomial of $a$ divides any polynomial $f$ such that $a$ is a root of $f$. So if $f$ is irreducible then the only factors of $f$ are $c\cdot m$ where $c$ is a constant and $m$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$. If you assume both polynomials to be monic you get that $f=m$.